# Entry box with validation deletes data

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

From this python code I have used a validation check that only allows integers and spaces to be inserted in the entry box. But when rewriting the code back into the box in line `array_entry.insert(0, alist)` the code self deletes itself. 
How would I fix this so that the modified array would enter back into the entry box without self deleting itself.
Thanks in advance (:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Array manipulation GUI")

def int_check_space(value, action):
    if action == '1':
        if value.isdigit():
            return True
        elif value == " ":
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True

array_entry = Entry(window, validate="all")
array_entry['validatecommand'] = (array_entry.register(int_check_space),'%S','%d')
array_entry.pack()

def run():
    alist = [int(x) for x in array_entry.get().split()]
    print(alist)
    array_entry.delete(0, END)
    array_entry.insert(0, alist)

calculate_button = Button(window,text="Calculate", command=run)
calculate_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you mean that when press `12<space>12` and click `Calculate`,the text will be deleted.Right?

Comment: exactly idk why that happens @jizhihaoSAMA

Comment: Because in your `int_check_space` function,you use a incorrect judgement.Try to use `if value.replace(" ","").isdigit():` instead of  `if value.isdigit():`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines:

```
#array_entry.delete(0, END)
#array_entry.insert(END, alist)
```